# View show page for menu item in Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I would like to dynamically change the menu based on the permissions of the viewing user. I would like the superadmin user to have access to the normal Resource actions (index, show, update, etc). So when an admin clicks on a menu item, it would take them to the index of that resource. I would like to restrict the normal admin user to just viewing a specific show page.

The menu route for the superadmin would be: /admin/resource
The menu route for the normal admin would be: /admin/resource/id

I would also like to restrict normal admin access to the index view, or other resources that they don't have access to. I have been able to achieve both these things, but I have yet to be able to map a menu item to a specific show page. I know I could create a custom page and view, but I really would like to share the custom DSL for the show and edit pages between superadmin and the normal admin.

Anyone know how to make this happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I figured a way to get what I want. I am not sure if exactly fulfills what I wanted. (meaning, it would be nice to create custom menu items that are mapped to specific resources)

I just overwrote the index controller action to redirect to the specific show page. Because the super admin needs access to the original Store resource, I had to alias it with :as.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Store, :as => 'My Store' do
  menu :if => proc{ !current_user.is_admin? },
       :label => 'My Store'

  actions :show, :edit, :update

  controller do
    def index
      redirect_to(admin_my_store_url(current_user.store))
    end
  end
end
```